Not able to receive MAVLINK_MSG_ID_MAG_CAL_PROGRESS
I am currently in the process of integrating Mission Planner’s Compass Calibration feature into my custom Qt / C++ application. I have successfully initiated the compass calibration procedure by sending the MAV_CMD_DO_START_MAG_CAL command. However, despite the calibration process executing without any apparent issues, I am encountering a lack of feedback or progress reports pertaining to the compass calibration status (Not able to receive MAVLINK_MSG_ID_MAG_CAL_PROGRESS or MAVLINK_MSG_ID_MAG_CAL_REPORT.)
My objective is to dynamically visualize the progress of the compass calibration process within the user interface using a progress bar. Could you kindly advise on potential reasons for the absence of feedback or progress updates?
